# Generics in an interface in a nested function

Tags: typescript

```
interface Maybe<A> {
  // this works as expected
  a: <B>(a: A, b: Maybe<B>) => Maybe<B>;

//# Maybe#chain :: Maybe a ~> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
  // this does not
  chain: <B>((a: A) => Maybe<B>) => Maybe<B>;
}
```

How can I express function expecting a function and sharing type variable on both "levels" as shown in snippet? Or is TypeScript's type system too weak to express it?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I forgot to name an argument. Working version (notice the `fn`):

```
  chain: <B>(fn: (a: A) => Maybe<B>) => Maybe<B>;
```